# How can I make Swagger read SpringMVC annotations

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger

While reviewing a piece of code I encountered a heavily annotated function, which included something along the lines of

`@ApiParam(value = "order number", required = false) @RequestParam(value = "order", required = true)`

`required = false` vs. `requires = true` looks very suspicious, it's probably a bug. The repetition in the annotations is an obvious cause for such bugs. Why would Swagger not be able to simply read the @RequestParam annotation, making the @ApiParam annotation obsolete, or at least optional?

How would I do this elegantly?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the latest `spring-fox`? According to the [Docs](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/snapshot/), you'll only need to use the `@ApiXX` when the behaviour/model cannot be extracted from MVC/Jackson annotations:

> **1.2. Goals**
>
> Philosophically, we want to discourage using (swagger-core) annotations that are not material to the service description at runtime. For e.g. the jackson annotations should always trump or have more weight than @ApiModelProperty or for e.g. @NotNull or **specifying @RequestParam#required should always win**. Annotations are to to be used only to supplement documentation or override/tweak the resulting spec in cases where its not possible to infer service/schema characteristics.

So even though the `@ApiParam` specifies a conflicting value for `required`, the generated api-docs by springfox will use the `@RequestParam` value.